# Linux & Visual Studio Code: super + e

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code

I just installed Visual Studio code a few minutes ago, and now I have this problem. When I press super + e instead of opening my explorer it now opens visual studio with it's explorer open. Obviously I do not want visual studio to be opened everytime I press this shortcut and would like to be able to use it to browse through files. Thanks for any help.

Update: It seems to have replaced the default explorer for alot of things, for example if I click on removable drives then click file manager, the folder will open up in vscode.

Comment: It would be very useful if you tell which Linux and WM you use, e.g Ubuntu (unity) or Ubuntu (gnome), etc...

Usually you can replace that in system configuration -> about or Preferred applications

Comment: I'm using Linux mint with cinnamon.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I figured out the solution, so the default file browser is called nemo for anyone who doesn't know. I simply had to use the command below in the terminal to set nemo as the default browser again and now it's all good.

xdg-mime default nemo.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search

Answer (score 7):

For deepin 15.10 use

> xdg-mime default dde-file-manager.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search

Comment: For Gnome 3.38 on Arch use: xdg-mime default org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search

Answer (score 2):

I find the ans from [super + e opens VS Code on Linux Deepin](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/109807)

> The solution is to change the order of apps
> open
> `code /usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache`
> find
> `inode/directory`
> assign `code.desktop;dde-file-manager.desktop;`to it

The above solution is useful and directly for me to solve the problem.I just need to edit the file `/usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache`, move `dde-file-manager.desktop;` to the position which is former than vscode.

BTW, I have tried to type `xdg-mime default dde-file-manager.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search` in my terminal but it seems nothing happen.

Answer (score 0):

For the case where your **default file explorer** is **gnomes nautilus "files"**:

```
xdg-mime default org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search
```